# What could possibly go wrong if I replace all "int"s with "long"s?

Tags: java, types

Let's say I had over 2 billion objects with a unique `int` id field and decided that I needed to extend that. I replace all the relevant `int` tokens in the code with `long` and perform the conversion in my database. Intuition tells me something would go horribly horribly wrong, but I can't figure out what. What would go horribly horribly wrong?

Comment: *"What would go horribly horribly wrong?"* - You could be mauled by a leopard that was hiding under your desk.  Come on ... use your imagination.  I'm sure you could think of LOTS of things that could go wrong.

Comment: @Sneftel the question is tagged Java, where `int` and `long` are specifically _not_ the same size

Comment: Just do it by copying to another column, then converting, then deleting the original, then renaming the copy to the original's name. Test it by comparing values somewhere in between, and you should be safe.

Comment: @AdamAdamaszek if there's a DB involved you'd also have to replace JDBC `getInt` calls with `getLong`, etc.

Comment: You use a version control system for your code, right? So just give it a try.

Comment: @StephenC, I can't think of these many things, which is why I asked the question.

Comment: @AndrewSzeto one consideration is that in JS arrays and any Collection that's accessible by index, the array offset can only be an `int`.  Hopefully you're never storing more than 2B items in a single memory-resident array at once, though...

Comment: Just came up with one: function calls to external APIs would fail, since they would be called with longs instead of ints.

Comment: @Alnitak Or maybe just change type="int" to type="long"? I was talking about the concept, not particular implementation, how do you know he is using pure JDBC, not JDBI, or Hibernate?

Answer (score 2):

If you take proper precautions like:

- testing your code properly,
- doing a trial conversion on a development server using a snapshot of the production data,
- using proper configuration management on your production system,
- backing up your production database before you start the real conversion,
- etcetera

then the worst case is that you might need to recover from the backup if the conversion fails ... or you discover *bad things* soon afterwards.

In short, this is not that different to any change that modifies the database schema.

Comment: +1 It could go horribly wrong but with decent testing most likely you could have it working pretty quickly.  Not has horrible as having "unique" ids which have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a fairly low risk change, in that anything that is going to go wrong will most likely be found at compile time. Just be careful of anything you are calling through reflection, placing into raw collections, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This situation somewhat based on mistakes I've seen/made. It's also somewhat contrived, but it sounds like you're looking for imaginative answers...

Suppose you've got a JDBC wrapper in which parameters are bound to queries using a `bind` method that's overloaded as `void bind(String name, int x)`, `void bind(String name, long x)`, ... rather than separately-named `setInt`, `setLong`, ... methods.

And suppose someone got into the habit of always including a redundant cast when calling these methods (e.g. `query.bind("personId", (int) person.getId());` to make the target method explicit, so that, for instance, the return type of `person.getId()` couldn't be changed to `String` without introducing a compile error (so anyone changing that aspect of the person class would be forced to come look at this query and make sure it still makes sense).

Now suppose that in your refactor to change the person ID from `int` to `long`, you forget to change one of these casts from `(int)` to `(long)`, and the `int` cast that used to be redundant is now a narrowing operation.

Three years down the road, when the identifier sequence rolls past `2^31`, suddenly that cast (which ironically was supposed to be defensive) is now truncating identifiers, quietly corrupting your database.